# vsftpd: virtual user not able to upload file or create directory

Tags: configuration, vsftpd

I created 2 virtual users for ftp (vsftpd): bholu1 and bholu2
I wanted bholu1 to have write access, access to make directory and upload permission. For that I have set up the user bholu1 as below but still he isn't able to upload file or create a directory. 
( I have followed [this link](ftp://vsftpd.beasts.org/users/cevans/untar/vsftpd-3.0.2/EXAMPLE/VIRTUAL_USERS_2/README) to achieve this)

See below: I have set per-user configurability for both user :bholu1 and bholu3

```
ravbholua@ravi:/etc/vsftpd_user_conf$ pwd
/etc/vsftpd_user_conf
ravbholua@ravi:/etc/vsftpd_user_conf$ cat bholu1
anon_world_readable_only=NO
write_enable=YES
anon_upload_enable=YES
ravbholua@ravi:/etc/vsftpd_user_conf$ cat bholu3
anon_world_readable_only=NO
ravbholua@ravi:/etc/vsftpd_user_conf$
```

Both are able to read the login directory. But as per the configuration for bholu1, he should be able to upload as well as create a new directory but he isn't able to do so.

Please see below the conf. file:

```
ravbholua@ravi:/etc$ cat vsftpd.conf
pam_service_name=/etc/pam.d/vsftpd.virtual
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd_user_conf
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES

#write_enable=NO
#anon_upload_enable=NO
#anon_mkdir_write_enable=NO
#anon_other_write_enable=NO
anon_world_readable_only=YES

chroot_local_user=YES

guest_enable=YES
guest_username=virtual

listen=YES
listen_port=10021

pasv_min_port=30000
pasv_max_port=30999

ravbholua@ravi:/etc$
```

It doesn't make any difference even if I uncomments all lines which are commented as shown above in the config. file.

Also have a look below to see what happens when bholu1 logs in ftp server:

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ ftp -p rs 10021
Connected to ravi.com.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
Name (rs:ravbholua): bholu1
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> put soul.txt
local: soul.txt remote: soul.txt
227 Entering Passive Mode (109,202,101,166,117,249).
553 Could not create file.
ftp> mkdir a
550 Permission denied.
ftp>
```

May I request you to say what am I missing in my configuration.

Comment: Fistly, I would uncomment and change 'write_enable=NO' to 'write_enable=YES'

Try that and let us know if bholu1 still has a problem creating files and dirs

Comment: @andrew I had checked this earlier also. Now also I checked by changing from 'write_enable=NO' to 'write_enable=YES'. Still bholu1 isn't able to create directories or upload any files from local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for virtual users to enable write access:

```
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
```